# Gap where soffit meets roof

Tags: roof, hole, soffit

A racoon has been getting in the soffit for the last few weeks.  I have tried trapping him with no success.  The roof is to steep for me to climb up.  A roofer looked at it and didn't know how to successfully close up the gap so the racoon could not get back in.  Does anyone have suggestions on how I can close this permanently?I used mesh cloth on the inside to keep him from getting in the attic but he is just sleeping in the soffitt now.  Any help is appreciated. [[image: closeup of the hole][1]]

Answer (score 1):

If you can reach the soffit from the attic, try weighing that corner down with a few bricks and then wedging them down with a 2x4 to straighten out the soffit. It's usually cramped up there but there might be enough room to get your arm through and drop in a few bricks.

Answer (score 0):

Raccoons are persistent and industrious. I would first remove the problem (raccoon) by calling a wildlife trapper. Sometimes your local government has an agency that will take care of the problem.  Then call a handyman to close the opening. It looks like the soffiting is just bent up out of place where it meets the roof. While getting that repaired ask the service provider to look for any other possible ports of entry and correct those too.